# ImportError: No module named numeric

Tags: python, importerror, python-import

I get the following error 
ImportError: No module named numeric if I have the following import

```
 from numeric import *
```

in my python source code. How do I get this running on my Windows box against a python 2.7.x compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably need to install this module: [Link](https://numpy.org/)
There are binaries for windows too, so installation should be easy.

Josh

Answer (score 7):

There *is* a module called numeric, but it's been deprecated for years in favour of numpy. You probably want to update your code to use numpy instead.

If you really need numeric, you can get it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/Old%20Numeric/24.2/), but you'll have to compile it from source for Python 2.7, because the latest binaries are for 2.4.

Comment: Although that was `Numeric`, not `numeric`.

Comment: @MichaelHoffman: True, but on a case insensitive windows machine, I guess imports work either way.

Answer (score 2):

There is no common module called `numeric`. Are you sure you don't mean `import numpy`?